# e- and f- versions of commands

Tags: command-line

I noticed that some commands also come in with e- and f- versions, e.g. grep, egrep, fgrep and a few others.

Is there some pattern or a naming convention if a particular command should have e- or f-version?

Comment: What other commands have you seen with the same naming pattern?

Comment: @JosephR. perhaps the OP is thinking of `fsck` and `e2fsck`? That's the only one I can think of that at least comes close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a clue about this in, e.g., `man grep`, which is also `man fgrep` and `man egrep` -- very often tools with minor variations like this will have one man page for all the variations, explaining them in relation to one another:

> In addition, two variant programs egrep and fgrep are available. 
>   `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`.  `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`.  **Direct
>   invocation as either egrep
>          or fgrep is deprecated**, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

Presumably, fgrep and egrep were once standardized names, but if you look further down the man page note that `-E` and `-F` are "specified by POSIX", implying this standardization changed tack, but (as stated above), [backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) is maintained.

On the topic of whether programs 'should' have variants - no, there is no standard.  But there are a lot of programs that do so thanks to the light-weight nature of links (see `ln` - ignore symbolic links).